# Limit characters number on Ckeditor in Symfony

Tags: symfony, ckeditor

I'm using the Ckeditor bundle on Symfony, and I'm trying to set the characters limit for the form field with the displaying the remained chars counter.

I found information about props like "maxLength", "maxChar", "maxWord" and so on, but it not works:

```
$builder->add('description', CKEditorType::class, [
        'config' => array(
            'uiColor' => '#ffffff',
            'toolbar' => [ [ "Image", "-", "Styles", "Format", "-", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "-", "Maximize" ] ],
            'maxChar' => 2,
            'showCharCount' => true

        ),
    ]);
```

On the official Ckeditor documentation is mentioned about a [special plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/wordcount) for this, but I don't know, if it works with Symfony. Does anybody know, how to set it?

Tnanks for your answers.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/IvoryCKEditorBundle/usage/plugin.html

Comment: OK, thanks @pbenard for this link. The other case, that the solution, indicated there is not working for me, but that's another deal :)

Comment: How do you want to deal between to ckeditor reformat ? Exemple, a sentence is formatted in a 'p' tag but could be in a 'div' tag too. Maybe you can play directly with ckeditor events to do your business...